# Poisson Distributions: Have Daily Rate and "peak rate", how to figure out hourly rate?

Tags: poisson-distribution, interarrival-time

I know that the daily average number of customers per 11 hours is 610 and during the highest peak of the day (from 12 to 1) 100 customers are served  with the second peak (from 6 to 7)  50 customers are served. How can I figure out the average rate per each hour of the day? The first mode is from 11 am to 4 pm and the second mode is from 4 pm to 10 pm. Both modes are assumed to conform to a Poisson distribution respectively.

Comment: Could you point out any information that would indicate the answer is not $610/11$?  Or else could you indicate what kind of answer you are looking for?

Comment: Given that the arrival rate is time dependent (more customers come in around lunch time and dinner time), that means that the average arrival rate for each hour is not the same and that's why I don't think its 610/11. I don't know if I can just use one Poisson distribution for the daily arrivals which is 610 because that would not capture the second peak for dinner time. The answer I'm looking for is how to find a bimodal distribution (both modes follow Poisson distributions) given the information I provided.

Comment: Granted, I don't know much at all about statistics. I'm trying to figure this out for a discrete event simulation problem. I don't have the average arrivals for each entire mode, I just have the overall average arrivals for the whole day and the average arrivals for each peak.

Comment: Although you have *observed* an apparent time dependence, you haven't given us any information whatsoever about your model for that time dependence.  Without that, there's little anyone can do.

Comment: I'm not sure what information is needed. It's an M/M/1, single channel, multiphase queueing model.

Comment: M/M/1 models typically follow a Poisson distribution in terms of arrival rate and exponential distribution for service rates. However, I'm trying to deviate from this by creating a bimodal distribution for arrivals. I'd like to be able to calculate it with the given information but I guess what you're trying to tell me is that there's no way to do that without data.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the "M"s in the M/M/1 refer to the assumption of a homogeneous Poisson process. The latter may be (essentially, up to technicalities) described by the Poisson distribution of the event counts in arbitrary intervals *with expectation proportional to the length of the interval*, or alternatively, by the exponential distribution for the inter-arrival times of events.

Your arrival process is not homogeneous, and a non-homogeneous Poisson process is likely an appropriate model for it. You may impose some constraints on the rate function. Perhaps something similar to what you want to do is discussed in [this paper](http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/EstimatingNonhomogPoisson96.pdf).